# Applescript to monitor terminal changes

Tags: terminal, applescript, notifications

I want to be able to check if a word appears in a terminal window running a java application and then display a notification. Any ideas?

Comment: iTerm2 has triggers that do this: http://www.iterm2.com/triggers.html#/section/home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tell application "Terminal"
    repeat 120 times -- ~ 2 minutes
        if contents of front window contains "word" then
            say "match"
            -- insert your code here
            exit repeat
        else
            delay 1
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thnx! Do you know how I can run this script for each of my terminal tabs?